# Shopping cart rule for a particular set of SKU's in a category

Tags: shopping-cart-price-rules

How can i set a shopping cart rules for particular set of SKU's in a category. I have tried below condition but the rules applies for all SKU's in a category.

> If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE :
>
> If an item is FOUND  in the cart with ALL  of these conditions true:
>
> SKU  is one of SKU1,SKU2,SKU3

Comment: you added what you have done so far.but can you tell what actually you need to do.

Comment: I need to apply rule only for the particular number of SKU's in a category. I dont want to apply for all SKU's in a category. Can you suggest any solution?

Comment: see my answer below that should work normally

Answer (score 1):

You can use this

If ALL of these conditions are TRUE :

If an item is FOUND in the cart with ALL of these conditions true:

Category is one of Category 1 ,2 ,3

[image: See here]

Comment: I have tried by adding below rule. But still it fails.   

If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE :
If an item is FOUND  in the cart with ALL  of these conditions true: 

SKU  is one of  SKU1,SKU2  
SKU  is not one of  SKU3,SKU3,SKU3

In Actions, I have made selected "percent of product price discount" and Discount Amount.

Apply the rule only to cart items matching the following conditions (leave blank for all items)

If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE :
Category  is  2

Comment: what if you just use the categoriy selector and not the skus ?

Comment: It will apply to all SKU's available in a category. I need only for some SKU's rule to be applied for a category and not for all SKU's.

Comment: Ya then you have to add the category and the sku then that should work

Answer (score 0):

This scenario will get successful only if we add rules in Actions.

An important thing is the attribute SKU should be added in Cart Item Attribute. If an attribute is not included in cart item attribute but included in product attribute, then the rule will be applied to all SKU's in the category.

Please find the below rule for your reference.
[image]

In the above rule, SKU attribute is selected from cart item attribute.